# problem in installing dnsproxy on Lucid

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, ubuntu-10.04, package-management

I am trying to install dnsproxy on a Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit server but this is failing.

```
root@some:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# aptitude install dnsproxy 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done 
The following NEW packages will be installed: 
  dnsproxy libevent-1.4-2{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 78.0kB of archives. After unpacking 299kB will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y 
Writing extended state information... Done 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main libevent-1.4-2 1.4.13-stable-1 [61.4kB] 
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe dnsproxy 1.15-6build1 [16.6kB] 
Fetched 78.0kB in 0s (80.8kB/s) 
Selecting previously deselected package libevent-1.4-2. 
(Reading database ... 50972 files and directories currently installed.) 
Unpacking libevent-1.4-2 (from .../libevent-1.4-2_1.4.13-stable-1_amd64.deb) ... 
Selecting previously deselected package dnsproxy. 
Unpacking dnsproxy (from .../dnsproxy_1.15-6build1_amd64.deb) ... 
Processing triggers for man-db ... 
Processing triggers for ureadahead ... 
Setting up libevent-1.4-2 (1.4.13-stable-1) ... 

Setting up dnsproxy (1.15-6build1) ... 
 * Starting dnsproxy dnsproxy                                                                                                                                          /usr/sbin/dnsproxy: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/dnsproxy: undefined symbol: event_sigcb 
                                                                                                                                                                [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnsproxy, action "start" failed. 
dpkg: error processing dnsproxy (--configure): 
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Processing triggers for libc-bin ... 
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 dnsproxy 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover: 
Setting up dnsproxy (1.15-6build1) ... 
 * Starting dnsproxy dnsproxy                                                                                                                                          /usr/sbin/dnsproxy: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/dnsproxy: undefined symbol: event_sigcb 
                                                                                                                                                                [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnsproxy, action "start" failed. 
dpkg: error processing dnsproxy (--configure): 
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 dnsproxy 
Reading package lists... Done             
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done 
Writing extended state information... Done
```

Does any one has any idea as why is that failing?

Answer (score 0):

The `dnsproxy` init script is failing.  Why... well, that's rather a tricky question to answer, but if something doesn't install cleanly it's by-definition a bug, and should be reported.  You can get more visibility into what's going on with the init script by running it with `/bin/sh -x /etc/init.d/dnsproxy start` and seeing what happens.